# Does the master theorem applies to this recurrence?

Tags: recurrence-relation, master-theorem

The recurrence:

$T(n) = pT(n/q) + \log n$

for p < q and p >= 2.

So, I've figured out it would fall into case 1, since we have $n^{log_{q}p} = n^r  $, for $0<r<1$, which would mean that $f(n) = \log n$ would be dominated by a polynomial factor, i.e $\log n  = O(n^{r-e})$ for  $0 > e < r$. But according to my professor, this is wrong, and, even though it's dominated, it isn't by a polynomial factor. So, who's right after all?

Comment: Why don't you ask your professor to explain?

Comment: he is too busy and I need to know it right now

Comment: Well, that's not how this site operates.

Comment: Sorry? Why not? Should I post it on stack overflow then ?

Comment: Questions here are for posterity. There is no sense of urgency.